# Significance of man relative to God

Tags: theology

God is totally infinite in space/time and beyond, all-powerful, all-knowing, all-everything.

Compared to God, man, the universe, and everything in it - everything is completely insignificant.

If so, why does God deem man significant enough to warrant creating him and to bestow kindness to him.

If I were to bestow kindness to a bacteria would this be considered a kindness? if all the bacteria on the rug would pray to me, would I consider it worthy of my attention? The difference between G-d and man, according to Rabbi Avigdor Miller (Tape: supporting the fallers) is infinitely greater than the difference between man and a bacteria.

Comment: Why wouldn't kindness to a bacteria be kindness?

Comment: point it is you wouldnt deem it worthy of your attention

Comment: It would be a sign of my greatness to spend time on something so insignificant relative to me

Comment: ok, but not something infinitely insignificant relative to you

Comment: Just goes even greater. To quote R' Kook: מה קטנו מעשיך ה'. (it is amazing how much Hashem put into things so small)

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T2608

Comment: Hashem told us why He considers us significant: it's not good to be alone.